# ios webview how to monitor the webview load a new url

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, httprequest

**Situation is like this，my webview load a base request url，when user clicked the html or anyother action，the webview will laod a new url. Can I get the webview changed events? If window.location.href can be worked well，and how？

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

this method will be performed every time you click the button of html

Comment: I know this methods, but I dont not know the webview did it jmup into a new url ,you mean use UIWebViewNavigationType?

Comment: because any request will access this methods,how do I differentiates them?

Comment: @fredZhu make a break point,print the request.URL ,you will see the url of your action

Comment: Maybe I know how to do it,because i am doing Hybird programming，js methods will access too!